# While loop designed to break on null user entry, doesn't break on null user entry

Tags: java, user-input, while-loop

I'm making an app that lets people make surveys. My idea is to let people enter unlimited choices for a question, and to signal when they're done with that question by pressing Enter on a new line, at which point I let them enter the next question and that question's choices. I thought that pressing Enter on an empty line would result in a null, and wrote the while loop condition to break on null, but as the code is, below, it doesn't break on null, but carries right on asking users for more choices. Then I thought maybe an empty line is actually "" instead of null. But when I do that...NullPointerException. I hope I'm making sense here.

Essentially, the question is, how do I make the inner loop break and proceed to the next iteration of the outer loop?

Thanks!

```
public class Survey implements Serializable {
    String title = "";
    ArrayList<Question> questions;
    String surveyFileName;
//survey entry code
//entry is a Scanner defined in the Main class
while ((currentQn.questionContent = (Main.entry.nextLine())).equals("") == false) {
            currentQn.choices.clear();
            System.out.println("Please enter the text of question " + currentQnNo + ": ");
            String currentChoice = "";
            int currentChoiceNo = 1;
            System.out.println("Please enter choice " + currentChoiceNo + " for question " + currentQnNo + ": ");
            while ((currentChoice = (Main.entry.nextLine())) != null) {
                System.out.println("Please enter choice " + currentChoiceNo + " for question " + currentQnNo + ": ");
                currentQn.choices.add(currentChoice);
                currentChoiceNo++;
            }
            currentQnNo++;
            questions.add(currentQn);
        }
```

and here's Question's implementation:

```
package surveyor;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

class Question implements Serializable {
    public String questionContent = ""; //initialize these so no NPEs
    public ArrayList<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

Comment: Please stop calling empty strings ("") `null`.  They aren't null, they're empty.  There's a difference.

Comment: Yes, there's a difference. Then which one does Scanner get when you press Enter? Empty string, or null? That's my question.

Comment: Which line in your program raises the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: This should be very simple to test in a simple main() method - call Scanner.nextLine() and print "null!" or "empty!" depending on the return value

Comment: She isn't calling empty strings `null`. She originally thought `nextLine()` would return `null` for an empty line, but then decided it must return an empty string.

Comment: @erickson: great question. That's exactly the problem! The NPE was thrown when I added the new question to the ArrayList of questions, not when entering data. Also, what makes you think I'm a "she"? :P

Comment: Enter usually corresponds to carriage return or carriage return + new line, and this varies by platform. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2001-January/023997.html

Comment: Additionally, this is a very basic and ugly implementation. Suggest you refactor it to : create a method to make a question, create a method to make choices, create a class Choices and have Question have an ArrayList of that (this allows you nice things, like the ability for multiple selections via an boolean isValid property in the Choice class, etc)

Answer (score 0):

before inner while loop

```
 bool shouldContinue = false;
```

in inner while loop

```
if ("".equals(currentChoice.trim())) {
    shouldContinue = true;
    break;
}
```

after inner while loop

```
if (shouldContinue) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, never mind. The NPE was not for the empty string. It was for the `ArrayList<Question> questions`, which wasn't initialized. Scanner indeed gets an  empty string, not null.